# Search for a file on Sharepoint and return filename

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I had been using the below code to check if a file exists on a SharePoint site:

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXHTTP As Object
    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    If Not UCase(url) Like "HTTP:*" Then
        url = "http://" & url
    End If
    On Error GoTo haveError
        oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", url, False
        oXHTTP.send
        URLExists = IIf(oXHTTP.Status = 200, True, False)
    Exit Function

haveError:
        URLExists = False End Function
```

The problem now is that the file that I used to download now has the following format:

```
old url = teams.sharepoint.xyz.com\Daily Report - DDMMYYYY.XLS
new url = teams.sharepoint.xyz.com\Daily Report - v2 YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.XLS.XLS
```

I want to be able to grab the latest file from the server, and I am not sure how to go about doing that using wildcards. It used to work fine with the old url as I could easily format the date, but now that the new url has the Time added to it, I can't figure out a way to search the SharePoint site using, maybe, a wildcard search.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it worked out now:

```
   Function GetFullFileName(strfilepath As String, strFileNamePartial As String) As String
      Dim objFS As Variant
      Dim objFolder As Variant
      Dim objFile As Variant
      Dim intLengthOfPartialName As Integer
      Dim strfilenamefull As String

      Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strfilepath)

      'work out how long the partial file name is intLengthOfPartialName = Len(strFileNamePartial)

      'Instead of specifying the starting characters of the file you can directly loop through all files in the folder
      For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 

         'Test to see if the file matches the partial file name
         If Left(objFile.Name, intLengthOfPartialName) = strFileNamePartial Then
            'get the full file name
            strfilenamefull = objFile.Name
            Exit For
         Else

         End If
      Next objFile

      Set objFolder = Nothing
      Set objFS = Nothing

      'Return the full file name as the function's value
      GetFullFileName = strfilenamefull

   End Function

   Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
      Dim oXHTTP As Object
      Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
      If Not UCase(url) Like "HTTP:*" Then
         url = "http://" & url
      End If
      On Error GoTo haveError
      oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", url, False
      oXHTTP.send
      URLExists = IIf(oXHTTP.Status = 200, True, False)
   Exit Function

   haveError:
      URLExists = False 
   End Function
```

Then use the following code in the main function:

```
PrtFileName = "\\sharepointsite.com\path to folder"
PrtFileName2 = "sharepointsite.com/path to folder"
' ---------------------------------------
' Check source file exists using a loop
' to keep going back until a valid file
' is found within last 7 days.
' ---------------------------------------
Dim fileExists, a As Boolean
fileExists = False
Dim dateOffset As Integer
dateOffset = 0

Do While ((fileExists = False) And (dateOffset < 14))
    FileDate = "Daily Report - Remedy v2 " + Format(Now() - dateOffset, "YYYY-MM-DD")

    Filename1 = GetFullFileName(PrtFileName, FileDate)
    MsgBox PrtFileName + "\" + Filename1

    a = URLExists(PrtFileName2 + "/" + Filename1)

    If a = True Then
        'FileDate = Now()
        Filename = PrtFileName + "\" + Filename1
        MsgBox Filename
        fileExists = True
    Else
        a = False
        fileExists = False
        dateOffset = dateOffset + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Works like a charm. To open the excel workbook I use the following command:

```
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
```

If someone can make it more efficient then even better but it does the job for me for the moment.